# Does non existing resource in html slows down page rendering?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I have following html/js sample code,

```
<html>
<script scr="abc.src"/>
<html>
<div>
 Hello Mars!
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

I preprocess this html in my code, If there is abc.src tag inside the html, then I inject additional javascript function.  My Android WebView then loads everything after preprocessing html.

Since **abc.src**  doesn't actually exist, I can see in Chrome Debugger Network tab, it's spending few seconds to download non-existing resource until it fails loading.

However, I have never experienced delays of seconds while rendering the web page in Android WebView. Does having non existing resource like "abc.src" will slow down overall page rendering.

Comment: Is this a valid html?  it is preferred to place the scripts at the end of the body to boost rendering..

Comment: Take a look at the "defer" and "async" attribute for script tags. Both might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LazyLoad](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload) library, webview will render html first then load and execute js later.

I've used it to reduce render time on Android Webview, it worked great.